# How to make two dropdowns in one line in react?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, dropdown

I don't know what wrong I am doing but these two dropdowns are not rendering in one line, please someone help me to render them in one line

```js
import React from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Select from 'react-select';

function NavForRest() {

    const langOptions = [
                    { value: 'EN', label: 'EN' },
                    { value: 'HINDI', label: 'HINDI' },
                    { value: 'SANSKRIT', label: 'SANSKRIT' }
    ]
    
    const currencyOptions = [
                    { value: 'INR', label: 'INR' },
                    { value: 'INR', label: 'INR' },
                    { value: 'AUD', label: 'AUD' }
                    ]

    return (
            <div className="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between w-80 mt-0 mb-0" style={{"width":"80%", "margin":"auto"}}>

                <div style={{"display":"inline"}}>
                    <span>
                         <Select options={langOptions} />
                    </span>
                    <span>
                        <Select options={currencyOptions} />
                    </span>
                </div>
                </div>
    )
}

export default NavForRest;
```

Here is the output

[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEa78.png)

Comment: react-select will probably be a div. You need override either its style within CSS (use inspect element to find what class names the select boxes are using); OR pass in override classNames to the select components (depends if the component supports that or not).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1)** You can just use `flexbox` here and style in a single line as

This works because by default `flex-direction` is `row` so you just have add `display: flex` and It will arrange in single line

**Live Demo**

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

```
<div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
```

**`EXTRA INFORMATION: You can also use gap property to add some space in between flex-items`**

```
<div style={{ display: "flex", gap: "1rem" }}>
```

---

**2)** Since you are also using `bootstrap` here then you just have to add `d-flex` class and this alone will do work.

Answer (score 0):

use display flex

```
<div style={{"display":"flex"}}>
            <span>
                 <Select options={langOptions} />
            </span>
            <span>
                <Select options={currencyOptions} />
            </span>
        </div>
```